# code . command isn't working in windows10

Tags: node.js, windows, typescript, powershell, visual-studio-code

'code .' command was working fine but it suddenly stopped working. when I run 'code .' in PowerShell to open VScode I'm getting an error. I tried restarting the pc but it didn't solve the problem.
Please help me solve this.
Here is the error:

```
#
# Fatal error in, line 0
# Failed to deserialize the V8 snapshot blob. This can mean that the snapshot blob file is corrupted or missing.
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0000000B649FF2C0
 1: 00007FF6AC99FA7F node::Buffer::New+130927
 2: 00007FF6AC817C7A IsSandboxedProcess+1850986
 3: 00007FF6AB23E068 v8::Isolate::Initialize+744
 4: 00007FF6AC81D140 uv_mutex_unlock+21184
 5: 00007FF6A9E48D33 std::__1::__vector_base<v8::CpuProfileDeoptFrame,std::__1::allocator<v8::CpuProfileDeoptFrame> >::__end_cap+102515
 6: 00007FF6A9F06258 v8::internal::JSMemberBase::JSMemberBase+55064
 7: 00007FF6A9D713A0 Ordinal0+5024
 8: 00007FF6AFB1FB12 uv_random+18069154
 9: 00007FFF893F7C24 BaseThreadInitThunk+20
10: 00007FFF89B2D721 RtlUserThreadStart+33
```

Comment: Have you tried starting VS Code from the start menu? Or just `Code` alone. Perhaps a file that it is "remembering" from a prior session is corrupted?

Comment: Does it still start if you launch it manually? Or from the command prompt? This might not be a PowerShell issue, rather a VSCode issue. A quick Google search for the error message suggests reinstalling VSCode...

Comment: I tried to open vscode  from the start menu but it's not opening, but haven't tried reinstalling it

Comment: Does it open if you type `code -n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved when I uninstalled -> reinstalled VScode.